# WordPress Custom page integrate in different menu.

Tags: wordpress, menu

We know WordPress has a default page.php File. I want to create some custom page and integrate (Link) it to different menu. Would you like help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have access to the theme files you could create your own custom template file.

This is achieved by adding a page-{slug}.php to your theme folder or custom-page-template.php.

If you opt for the latter you will need to define a template naming block at the top of the template so WordPress can give you the page template option in the create section of the admin.

The block will look as follows:-

```
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: About Template
 **/
get_header(); ?>

/** Custom template html / php markup here **/

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

For more information WordPress has excellent documentation on this:-

[Page Templates Documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/page-templates/)

If you are looking to create another menu custom menu again this will depend on the current theme you are using and if you have access to edit.

To add a new menu you will need to register it and then call it within the section / template you need.

To register the menu you would use something similar to the following entered in the functions.php

```
function register_custom_menu() {
  register_nav_menu('custom-menu',__( 'Custom Menu' ));
}
add_action( 'init', 'register_custom_menu' );
```

To call this menu you would edit the template you wish the menu to appear in and add:-

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'custom-menu' ) ); ?>
```

After your menu is created you can add custom links to it via Appearence Menu

Comment: Thank you for response. Actually I have set 6 menu through 6 sidebar in my custom home page. I want to set 6 different left menu for each sidebar